# Animation in this canvas game only works once

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I’m trying to create a simple canvas game:

I have this code on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/michael23/pen/YyNKNo)

```js
var canvas;
var ctx;
var x = 300;
var y = 400;
var r = 0;
var mx = 0;
var my = 0;
var WIDTH = 600;
var HEIGHT = 400;


function circle(x,y,r) {
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.beginPath();
  var text = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000);
  var font = "bold " + (r*0.75) +"px serif";
  var textWidth = ctx.measureText(text).width;
  var textHeight = ctx.measureText("w").width;
  ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.moveTo(50, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(50, 10);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.moveTo(100, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(100, 10);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.moveTo(150, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(150, 10);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = "black"; // font color to write the text with
  ctx.font = font;
  ctx.fillText(text, x - (textWidth/2), y + (textHeight/2));
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';  
  ctx.stroke();
}
 
function clear() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}
 
function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  return setInterval(draw, 10);
}
 
function draw() {
  clear();
  circle(x, y, r);

  if (y>=350){
      y=y-0.5;
      r=r+0.3;
  }
  if (y<=350){
      y=y-1;
      x=x-0.75;
  }
  if (y<=50){
      x=x+0.75;
      r=r-0.2;
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
<button id="test" onclick="return init()">test</button>
```

By pressing the button you release bubbles and it has numbers rolling inside.

My questions are

1. How can I make the numbers stop at some point? I use random function for text value.
2. My button to launch bubbles only works once, I use `setInterval` to start the animation. What I want is to launch another bubble, and the previous bubbles would still continue the animation until they disappear.

Comment: Look at the console, you have an error there: `Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'arc' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The radius provided (-0.2) is negative.` (line 32)

Comment: You should try to put code here on stackoverflow.com, since external links tend to disappear. Also you should decouple the logic from drawing so the code is more maintainable. Use a variable to store the random number you wish to display, as property of the bubble, and manipulate it. Also, you use setInterval for drawing, you should read about RequestAnimationFrame if you plan to invest time on canvas.

Comment: I’ve made some [changes](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojZaGP?editors=001) to the CodePen. The radius became negative, I’ve included a check for that. Certain variables needed to be reset on each launch and the interval needed to be cleared before the radius became negative and before another button press.

Comment: @Xufox thanks for your correction to the codepen, I see you add radius check and a clear interval there. So if I want to add more bubbles I have to wait till previous animation ends or if I forced to press button while an animation still running it will be cleared and replaced with new animation, am I right?

Comment: @Elric thanks for your suggestion, will def try RequestAnimationFrame.

Comment: @michael Well, you can have multiple bubbles at once, you’d just have to program that…

Comment: @Xufox Yea I made a change to my code, I found a good reference from here. This is the result http://codepen.io/michael23/pen/xwqvpE . I know I should be able to add colors as variable too but I'm still learning so I'm quite satisfied with that. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Copy and paste the relevant code in the actual question :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't return setInterval in the init function
2. call your init function when the window has loaded using window.addEventListener("load", init);
3. Use window.requestAnimationFrame for animations

Hope this helps :)